# CSS causing xml to be positioned out of line

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am having a problem with what i think is my style sheet. My site page seems to be set up fine:

However, when i view it in a browser the middle document is out of line:

Could there be anything causing this to happen? it leads me to think maybe something in my css file is? But what? :(

My css file is as follows:

```
    div.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: white;
}

div.right
{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
}

div.center
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most probably due to your floating elements and since the center div is not floated at all, but rather "pushed" to the middle by the `float:left` of the left div.

If your `div`'s in the html are like:

```
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="left"> left </div>

    <div class="center"> center</div>

    <div class="right"> right</div>
</div>
```

Try floating the center div to the left also, and it should do the trick

```
div.center
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it was an easy fix :). If the answer is exactly what you where looking for, please take the time and `accept` the answer so it will be easier for others in the future with similar problems.

Comment: Just have, had to wait 5 minutes before i could set it as the answer ;)

Comment: When reducing the browser window size, instead of trying to consolidate the xml documents across the screen, it seems to stack them below each other. is this another problem with my css too?

Comment: if you don't have a parent div, yes since the items wont "fit" to the new window size, therefore the items go below one another. i'll edit the answer with a parent div that you should add as well with a desired width.